# Use aggregate in WHERE clause and OR

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I'm struggling to make my query work but don't manage to:

```
SELECT column1, MIN(column2) AS min_column2
FROM table1
WHERE column4 = 'hi'
GROUP BY column_id
HAVING (column3 > 0 OR min_column2 > 0)
```

I need to use `min_column2` with an `OR`, how would you do that?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have updated my initial post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix where and having

```
SELECT column1, MIN(column2) AS min_column2
FROM table1
WHERE column3 > 0 

HAVING min_column2 >
```

and for the correct use of aggregation function you should use group by eg:

```
SELECT column1, MIN(column2) AS min_column2
FROM table1
WHERE column3 > 0 
GROUP By column1
HAVING min_column2 >
```

the select of column not in aggregation function witout reference in group by is is deprecated  in sql and not allowed in the last version of mysql

due the fact you have changed  the question adding the missing group by and changing the rules  the new answer is

HAVING work on the result so if you want filter for column3 you must select this column too

```
  SELECT column1, column3, MIN(column2) AS min_column2
  FROM table1
  WHERE column4 = 'hi'
  GROUP BY column1, column3
  HAVING (column3 > 0 OR min_column2 > 0)
```

You must refer in group by the same columns in select that you don't use in aggregation function

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually your solution is the like if i'm using `AND` operand, but i need the `OR`, Someone before has gave me the solution but he/she deleted the reply!! I have updated my initial post with the solution

Comment: answer  updated .. (anyway remember that change the question is not fair)

Comment: thanks, I just forgot to mention the GROUP BY in my query, and i know it must be used with an aggregate function :) I have read about referring in the group by the columns not used in aggregate function, why is that? didn't understand much about it!

Comment: this is sql standard behavior  .. the use in select  of columns not in aggregation function is not allowed  is almost all the dbengine ...mysql allow  this (wrong behavior) until the mysql 5.6 . starting from mysql 5.7 also for mysql this is not more allowed ..  i repeat  .. is the normal SQL behavior

Comment: so if you are selecting for example 15 columns + 1 MIN(column), you'll have to refer in the GROUP BY all the 15 columns??

Comment: exactly ...  or join the the tables  and subselect  you need ..https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'll read it later :)
I'll have another question please if you don't mind. is it possible to have a nested query like this one: `SELECT column1, column2, (SELECT column3, column4 FROM table2 WHERE ...) FROM table1 WHERE ... ` ? Thanks

Comment: post a new question and comment me the link  .. is better  ...anyway is possible  ..  but not efficent ..

Comment: haha, I have to wait 90min to post a new one :) how about a discussion in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153496/discussion-between-websphere-and-scaisedge).